# Mac-Forums shadowblocking?

Tags: forums

I ran into a weird issue where Mac-Forums.com started running slowly while logged in and misdirecting to the home page or getting into redirect loops after a super-user or mod didn't like something I said trying to clarify an issue they misunderstood (not rudely in my opinion, but firmly and bluntly, and I was frustrated). When I could get the thread to load, I realized that they were offended, but now I'm unable to reach them because of the misloading, so I can't even show them what's happening or ask for any further info.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by meta. Regardless, I'm pretty sure an admin there set my account to be shadowblocked just because I pointed out some problems with their answers, in a futile attempt to help improve the process, but apparently they care more about their ego and image than helping people.

Comment: Hi again Steve. Meta is for discussions about this site - what’s on topic, and migration of questions and such…  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta It does take conversation and details to help people on these sites, so meta is a place to ask for help

Comment: Uh... the question was closed for being off-topic... :laugh:. So... apparently it's also not in the right place in webapps?